# Global error handler for Backbone.js ajax requests in Requirejs environment

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $         = require('jquery'),
        Backbone  = require('backbone'),
        Shell     = require('app/views/Frame/Shell'),
        Auth      = require('app/models/json/session');

    // Tell jQuery to watch for any 401 or 403 errors and handle them appropriately
    $.ajaxSetup({
        statusCode: {
            401: function(){
                // Redirect the to the login page.
                Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);            
            },
            403: function() {
                // 403 -- Access denied
                Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);
            }
        }   
    });

    return Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            "" : "home",
            "login" : "login",
            "logout" : "logout"
        },

        initialize: function (opt) {
            ev = opt.ev;            
            //Session.fetch();
        },

        home: function (id) {           
            new Dashboard({ev: ev});
        }

    });
});
```

The structure above I learned from http://clintberry.com/2012/backbone-js-apps-authentication-tutorial/ and I feel setting ajax error globally error like this not the proper way

What is the right way using backbone and requirejs?

Comment: That's how I would do it.  It may seem hacky, but it makes sense.  This to me reads as: "if there's an permission or authentication problem with any of the API calls, show the users the denied access page by redirecting them there."  For me, I actually just use "location.hash =". To really decouple jquery from backbone incase I decide to use a different library to handle the router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define(["Backbone"], function(Backbone){
    Backbone.ajax = function() {
        // Invoke $.ajaxSetup in the context of Backbone.$
        Backbone.$.ajaxSetup.call(Backbone.$, {
            statusCode: {
                401: function(){
                    // Redirect the to the login page.
                    Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);
                },
                403: function() {
                    // 403 -- Access denied
                    Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);
                }
            }
        });
        return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
    };    
});
```

Comment: hi @muhaimin-abdul, Is this any way to know which view, model or collection has called this ajax? means I want to know "cid" of that backbone object in "beforeSend" in ajaxsetup.

Comment: this is global settings for your next ajax ops. If you want to know the cid, you must have a reference within modular call